# AutoCompleteTextView not upgrading data

Tags: android, string, autocompletetextview

I'm trying to implement an AutoCompleteTextView with some data I get in the previous activity (via Intent). I'd like to display this data in the AutoCompleteTextView but it does not show any suggestions.

ArrayAdapter adapter;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.registro);


    acTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.calles);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String[] calles = intent.getStringArrayExtra("calles");

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Registro.this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,calles);
    acTextView.setThreshold(2);
    acTextView.setAdapter(adapter);
    //acTextView.setText(calles[250]);
```

Then, if I write 2 letters nothing is suggested. Any idea mateS?

Comment: Check your array, are you getting value in it from intent?

Comment: Yes, it has what it should have.

Comment: I solved this problem, changing the type of "calles" from String to ArrayList<String>